# Why hasn't anyone gotten the Generalist badge?

Tags: support, badges, stack-exchange

On Science Fiction & Fantasy SE, no one to date has earned the Generalist badge. I looked at one of the highest contributors (obviously not me), and here are the numbers in the site's top 40 tags:

- **story-identification   95**
- **harry-potter   1786**
- **star-trek  617**
- **star-wars  2068**
- **movie  169**
- **comics 88**
- **lord-of-the-rings  645**
- **marvel-comics  108**
- doctor-who   8
- **dc-comics  78**
- **star-trek-tng  179**
- tv   13
- futurama 0
- **books  65**
- **time-travel    113**
- **short-stories  15**
- **x-men  60**
- novel    4
- **aliens 58**
- **magic  68**
- avengers 5
- **tolkien    141**
- **stargate   46**
- a-song-of-ice-and-fire   0
- **batman 45**
- **superman   46**
- **the-matrix 65**
- **video-games    29**
- game-of-thrones  0
- george-r-r-martin    0
- suggested-order  7
- **technology 56**
- **voldemort  159**
- **star-trek-voyager  56**
- plot 0
- **robots 96**
- battlestar-galactica 0
- **stargate-sg1   17**
- **the-hobbit 127**
- **fantasy-genre  35**

If you count them up, that's 28 tags where the user has >15 score. Yet no one has been awarded the Generalist badge on the whole site? Is this a bug?

Comment: But are they all top 40 tags?

Comment: @HugoDozois - yes, those are the top 40 site tags

Comment: [See also.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/how-is-generalist-badge-supposed-to-work).

Comment: @Keen - I don't know how I missed that. Exactly my question

Comment: I don't know if anyone could believe this but a moderator declined my flag to migrate this to sci-fi saying there was no evidence to support it.  I'm guessing it was declined by yesterday's expert.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason is likely that one or more of the [Top 40 tags does not at least have 200 questions associated with it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).

I'll bet if you check out each of the tags you'll find at least one or two of them have less than 200 questions. There have been multiple meta questions related to the less than adequate wording of the Generalist Badge and its bizarre classification as a silver badge.

Comment: Oops, I answered the same thing after your comment. I'll give you the accept though.

Answer (score 12):

Upon reviewing, after sizlettervariables' comment, only the top 11 tags have 200+ questions. Tag 40 is still only at 66 questions. According to the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) he provided, the site does not meet the badge criteria. My apologies for not researching this more thorough.